'The requested qty is not available' message hides too quickly
In a Magento 2.4.2 website,
the message 'The requested qty is not available' that appears in the product details page disappears too quickly.
I checked the code in the inspect element and I see that the message is removed from the code.
I thought of changing the code that removes the message, but I can't locate the file with that code.
When changing the quantity from the mini-cart or the Cart page, the message appears in a popup and closes only on a button click (maybe that's a theme's function).
Any help or ideas to make the message not appearing? I want it to stay open until the user closes it with a button click.
Thank you in advance.

@Dimitra
Hey,
I checked in default Magento
https://prnt.sc/ZAqfNTuwqe4r it does not disappear from product page, I think  its related to your theme js code, so you need to check in theme JS file.
Thank You!
